# Lamport's distributed mutual exclusion: wait-chain order clock

Tags: concurrency, mutual-exclusion

Regarding Lamport's mutual exclusion... Where messages are exchanged in the following sequence between nodes S, G1, and G2. G1 and G2 are the members of the group.

(for this, lets just assume that a1 is an acknowledgment of m1; a2 is an acknowledgment of m2)

```
S sends m1 to G1
S sends m1 to G2
G2 sends a1 to S
S sends m2 to G1
S sends m2 to G2
G2 sends a2 to S
G1 sends a2 to S
G1 sends a1 to S
```

Let the Lamport clocks at each node start at: S: 5, G1: 2, G2: 1...

In which order and at what times are m1 and m2 delivered and how would you list the sequence of messages with their times?

I appreciate any replies (NOTE: this is just an example problem - as I am actually trying to figure out how a calculated result looks like).